# ERROR: GNU libc not found!

Tags: compiling

While using `make.sh` command for toolchain, I encountered the following error:

```
Checking for toolchain prerequisites
Checking for GNU bash                     [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU binutils                 [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU bison                    [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU bzip2                    [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU coreutils                [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU diffutils                [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU findutils                [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU awk                      [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU CC                       [ DONE ]
Checking for GNU libc                     [ FAIL ]
ERROR: GNU libc not found!
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably miss the development libraries for libc. Try to install them using

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```